# Display table using data from object Angular

Tags: html, angular

Hello i want display table with header of names [John, Jane, Mike] and three rows with informations. It should show up like this

[image]

I have array of objects

```
objects = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      age: {
        id: 'asd',
        entries: [
          { secondName: 'Max', value: 'A' },
          { secondName: 'Maciej', value: 'B' },
          { secondName: 'Wini', value: 'C' },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      age: {
        id: 'bsd',
        entries: [
          { secondName: 'Krzys', value: 'D' },
          { secondName: 'Kamil', value: 'E' },
          { secondName: 'Mirek', value: 'F' },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Mike',
      age: {
        id: 'gef',
        entries: [
          { secondName: 'Jacuka', value: 'G' },
          { secondName: 'Ziomek', value: 'I' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
```

Currently i created this code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let obj of objects">{{ obj.name }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let entry of getAllEntries()">
      <td *ngFor="let obj of objects">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let ageEntry of obj.age.entries">
            <td *ngIf="ageEntry.value === entry.value">{{ ageEntry.value }}</td>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  `,
})
export class App {    
  getAllEntries(): Entry[] {
    const allEntries: Entry[] = [];
    for (let obj of this.objects) {
      for (let entry of obj.age.entries) {
        if (!allEntries.some((e) => e.value === entry.value)) {
          allEntries.push(entry);
        }
      }
    }
    return allEntries;
  }
}
```

My result is:

[image]

What i should fix to display this table corretly? I have too many rows, when i need only three rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So premises are:

1. you want to have total rows that equals the max number of entries in any object inside `objects`,
2. in each row you will have number of columns equal to number of objects in `objects`,
3. entries from your object (as element of `objects`) will be displayed vertically.

So first we'll see how many rows we need, i.e. find the max number of `entries` that any element of `objects` has:

- introduce `maxColumns: number = 0;` in your class and in `onInit`:

  this.objects.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.age.entries.length > this.maxColumns) this.maxColumns = obj.age.entries.length;
  });
- then you want that number to be iterable so that you can use it with `ngFor` directive, so introduce `arrayOfRows: any = [];` and in `onInit`, just after the previous code add: `this.arrayOfRows = Array(this.maxColumns).fill(0);` which is actually a way to populate new array with zeros (or any type/value, the point is to have the array to iterate over, whatever the elements are).

Now, we have everything ready for the html part:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let obj of objects">{{ obj.name }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let col of arrayOfRows; let i = index">
      <td *ngFor="let obj of objects">
        <ng-container *ngIf="obj.age.entries[i]">
          {{ obj.age.entries[i].value }}
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thus, with `let col of arrayOfRows` we render number of `tr`s that equal the maximum entries any object can have. Then we want inside one `tr` to have only the values (of `entries`) that hold that position in their object, so we add `let i = index` to use `i` in the next iteration. In this next iteration, for `td`s, we actually add a top-level non-DOM element used just for iteration - the `ng-container` - to make sure that with each `tr` we are having the number of `td`s that correspond to number of objects. Then, we start adding `td`s - put *only* if the object's `entries` have a value.

Full example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pcqrmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

You can also consider creating another array (like `arrayOfRows`) to use for iteration on `tr`s instead of using `objects` - the `objects` might have any number of elements, so if it's potentially high number, better just get the length of `objects` and use it to build an array:

introduce new array: `arrayOfColumns: any = [];` and in `onInit` populate it: `this.arrayOfColumns= Array(this.objects.length).fill(0);` and then in html change:

`<td *ngFor="let obj of objects">` to `<td *ngFor="let col of arrayOfColumns; let j = index">` and
`<ng-container *ngIf="obj.age.entries[i]">` to `<ng-container *ngIf="objects[j].age.entries[i]">`